# Interactive function for getting number of packages ready to upgrade?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Goal: Get number of packages ready to upgrade from minibuffer or console.

Remarks:
Package.el is hard to grasp for elisp beginner - many contexts, implicit state, etc...

emacsclient -e "(list-packages)" gives: "X packages can be upgraded: type "U" to mark them for upgrading", but it also creates a new explicit buffer.

Maybe it is possible to adjust list-packages from package.el to do this in hidden buffer?

Refreshing packages archive is handled by package-refresh-contents and it is beyond this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[`epl-find-upgrades`](https://github.com/rejeep/cask.el/blob/6eda29c90802c79218c33b514866330329199bb6/epl.el#L198) gives you a list of upgradable packages.  Just wrap your own command around this function, to print the name of each package returned.

Comment: Yes, it gives me that, but only if I use cask.
This one function has deps in many places in epl-*.el files.
It is a long road to extract desired functionality.

Comment: Use Cask then.  These `epl-*` represent a considerable effort to provide a nice API around various of package.el.  It was a long road writing these, too.

Comment: The question is - can I use Cask and el-get in the same time?

Comment: Don't know... I see not what might stand against it.  I'd just use package.el, and get rid of el-get